# Почему созданный Request в Laravel принимает не все данные?

Tags: php, laravel

Подскажите пожалуйста почему массив с photos не попадает в созднаный реквест?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если напрямую в контрелере за ддешить реквест то все корректно выводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
Контроллер

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function add(Request $request)
    {
       dd('это через Request', $request->all());        
    }
    
    
Созданный Валидатор CreateRequest

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

/**
 * @property Request $request
 */
class CreateRequest extends FormRequest

{
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return auth()->check();
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
           dd('это в созданном реквесте CreateRequest', $this->request->all());
    {
        
}


Форма

<form method="POST" action="add" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf

  <div class="form-group row background-item">
      <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-3 col-form-label">Фото</label>
      <div class="col-sm-9">

          <input id="photos" type="file" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="photos[]" multiple>
    </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Создать</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: А как именно CreateRequest создаётся и связан с запросом изначально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потому что файлы не лежат в `Illuminate\Http\Request`, если хочешь проверить файлы, то стучись к `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/requests#files